# Nginx settings in nginx.conf

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

It is my first time I am working with nginx and that't why I need advices:

I don't understand why am I not allowed to change the nginx.conf file, although I have changed it's permissions. ( it always showed "couldn't create a backup file while saving" )

But I need to set these options in it:

1) All files with .js, .css, .jpeg and so must be given from me/static

2) And also files must be given with headers, caching the files on the browser's side

thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still can't write to your nginx.conf you probably haven't successfully changed its ownership. Good. Don't do that.

Instead, give yourself (temporary) root permission by proceeding your edit command with 'sudo', e.g., 'sudo vim nginx.conf`. If that doesn't work you may have to log in as root and add yourself to the sudoers group.

For caching static files, you'll need to add a `Cache-Control "public"` header and an expiration to a location block. The expiration **must** be set explicitly or it wont work. E.g.:

```
location /static/ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

See [HttpHeadersModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) for further details.

Comment: couldn't you show me the answer on the second question? I even can't find it, thank you!